# vim syntax highlighting: region that starts with "#" and end with either "#" or end of line

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

### The situation

I am in the process of writing a vim syntax file for a language that allows inline comments following this scheme:

```
This is code # and here is comment # but this is code again
```

The language also allows comment to start with a "#" and end with a newline, like so:

```
This is code # and until the end of the line, this is a comment
```

### What I want

I would like both to be recognized by my syntax file as comments.

### What I've tried

When I use:

```
syn region comment start="#" end="#"
```

, the result is that comments are not delimited by newlines. Now, I've done some research and tried it with the following regex match:

```
syn match comment "#.+?(?=#|$)"
```

And that seems to work properly, but doesn't do what I want. It does end the inline comment by the second "#", but then starts a new comment from that hashtag until the newline.
[image: regular expression tester result]

How do I tell the vim syntax file to properly recognize the comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is pretty straightforward

```
syn region Comment start=/#/ end=/#/ end=/$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think another solution is to use code similar to string matching (without escaping, i.e. for strings you would use `"` instead of `#`):

```
syn match hashComment "#[^#]*\(#\|$\)"
```

Only we need the end marker to be either `#` or the end of the line (`$`). Matt's solution is probably cleaner, though.